# django upgrade from 1.3 to 1.9 generate TypeError: Item in ``from list'' not a string

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, upgrade

I am upgrading an old project in Django from version 1.3 to version 1.9.
I was able to manage some bugs and make the modifications but now I am stuck with an error that I don't understand.

Here is the error log:

```
Performing system checks...

/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py:37: RemovedInDjango110Warning: You haven't defined a TEMPLATES setting. You must do so before upgrading to Django 1.10. Otherwise Django will be unable to load templates.
  "unable to load templates.", RemovedInDjango110Warning)

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fee03cfb848>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/norore/programmation/jebifdjango/jebif-root/jebif/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    (r'^election/',     include('election.urls')),
  File "/home/norore/.virtualenvs/jebifdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/norore/programmation/jebifdjango/jebif-root/election/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from election.views import *
  File "/home/norore/programmation/jebifdjango/jebif-root/election/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.mail import *
TypeError: Item in ``from list'' not a string
```

So, I checked the election/urls.py module and I did'nt see what is wrong. Here is the source code:

```py
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from election.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^(?P<election_id>\d+)/$', vote),
    ('^(?P<election_id>\d+)/ok/$', TemplateView.as_view(template = "election/vote-ok.html")),
    ('^(?P<election_id>\d+)/results/$', results),
    ('^(?P<election_id>\d+)/mailing/$', mailing),
)
```

And I also checked the election/views.py module:
(Hard to read directly on StackOverflow? Here is the source code on my GitHub account: https://github.com/Norore/jebif-election/blob/master/views.py)

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8

from django.core.mail import *
from django.shortcuts import *

from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

from jebif import settings

import election.models as election

import datetime
import operator

def vote( request, election_id ) :
    el = election.Election.objects.get(id=election_id)
    if not el.opened :
        return render(request, "election/vote-closed.html")

    candidate_choices = [(c.id, c.label) for c in el.candidate.all()]

    def validate_candidates( value ) :
        if len(value) < el.min_choices :
            raise ValidationError(u"Sélectionnez au moins %d candidat(s)." % el.min_choices)
        if len(value) > el.max_choices :
            raise ValidationError(u"Sélectionnez au plus %d candidat(s)." % el.max_choices)

    def validate_passwd( value ) :
        if len(value) != 32 :
            raise ValidationError(u"Clef de vote invaide.")
        try :
            v = el.voter.get(passwd=value)
            if v.hasvoted :
                raise ValidationError(u"Clef de vote déjà utilisée.")
        except election.Voter.DoesNotExist :
            raise ValidationError(u"Clef de vote inconnue.")

    class VoteForm( forms.Form ) :
        voteA = forms.ChoiceField(label=u"Vote A : %s" % el.voteA_label, # Bilan moral - \"Approuvez vous le bilan moral de l'association ?\"",
                        choices=election.Vote._meta.get_field("voteA").choices,
                        widget=forms.RadioSelect)
        if el.voteB_label :
            voteB = forms.ChoiceField(label=u"Vote B : %s" % el.voteB_label, # Bilan financier - \"Approuvez vous le bilan financier de l'association ?\"",
                        choices=election.Vote._meta.get_field("voteB").choices,
                        widget=forms.RadioSelect)
        if el.max_choices > 0 :
            candidates = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label=u"Vote C : Renouvellement du Conseil d'Administration - "
                + u"\"Voulez-vous que la personne suivante fasse partie du Conseil d'Administration ?\""
                + ((u" (%d maximum)" % el.max_choices) if el.max_choices < el.candidate.count()
                        else u" (sélectionnez tous les candidats que vous souhaitez voir élus)"),
                        required=False,
                        choices=candidate_choices,
                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                        validators=[validate_candidates])
        passwd = forms.CharField(label=u"Clef du vote", 
                        max_length=32, min_length=32,
                        validators=[validate_passwd])

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = VoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() :
            d = form.cleaned_data

            trace = "%s %s(%s)" % (datetime.datetime.now(), request.META.get("REMOTE_HOST"), 
                        request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR"))

            voter = el.voter.get(passwd=d["passwd"])

            vote = election.Vote(election=el)
            vote.trace = trace
            vote.voteA = d["voteA"]
            vote.voteB = d["voteB"] if "voteB" in d else 0
            vote.save()
            vote.choices = d["candidates"] if "candidates" in d else []
            voter.hasvoted = True
            voter.trace = trace
            vote.save()
            voter.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("ok/")
    else :
        form = VoteForm()
    context = { "election": el, 
                "form": form,
              }
    return render(request, "election/vote.html", context)



def is_admin() :
    def validate( u ) :
        return u.is_authenticated() and u.is_staff
    return user_passes_test(validate)

@is_admin()
def results( request, election_id ) :
    el = election.Election.objects.get(id=election_id)

    nb_voters = el.voter.count()
    total = el.vote_set.count()
    participation = (100.*total)/nb_voters

    def make_pc( e, t ) :
        if t > 0 :
            e["pc"] = (100.*e["nb"])/t
        else :
            e["pc"] = 0.

    def make_votes( r ) :
        get_nb = operator.itemgetter("nb")
        r.sort(key=get_nb, reverse=True)
        t = sum(map(get_nb, r))
        for e in r :
            make_pc(e,t)
        return t

    def make_abstained( e ) :
        make_pc(e, total)

    def tristate_result( field ) :
        r = []
        a = None
        for (val, label) in election.Vote._meta.get_field(field).choices :
            d = {"value": val, "label": label, "nb": el.vote_set.filter(**{field: val}).count()}
            if val != 0 :
                r.append(d)
            else :
                a = d
        make_votes(r)
        make_abstained(a)
        return {"votes": r, "abstained": a}


    aC_nb = el.vote_set.exclude(choices__in=el.candidate.all()).count()
    aC = {"nb": aC_nb}
    make_abstained(aC)

    base = total - aC_nb
    rC = []
    for c in el.candidate.all() :
        nb = c.vote_set.count()
        rC.append({"candidate" : c, "pc": (100.*nb)/base, "nb": nb })
    rC.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("pc"), reverse=True)

    results = {
        "voteA" : tristate_result("voteA"),
        "voteB" : tristate_result("voteB"),
        "voteC" : {"votes": rC, "abstained": aC}
    }
    context = { "election": el,
                "nb_voters": nb_voters,
                "participation": participation,
                "total": total, 
                "results": results,
              }
    return render(request, "election/results.html", context)


@is_admin()
def mailing( request, election_id ) :
    el = election.Election.objects.get(id=election_id)

    def validate_template( value ) :
        if not "%ELECTION_PASSWD%" in value or not "%ELECTION_URL%" in value :
            raise ValidationError(u"Macros %ELECTION_URL% ou %ELECTION_PASSWD non présentes")

    class MailingForm( forms.Form ) :
        email_to = forms.ChoiceField(label=u"Destinataires", choices=[
                        ("hasnotvoted", u"Seuls les inscrits n'ayant pas voté"),
                        ("allvoters", u"Tous les inscrits au vote"),])
        email_from = forms.EmailField(label=u"Expéditeur", initial="iscb.rsg.france@gmail.com")
        email_subject = forms.CharField(label=u"Sujet", initial="[JeBiF] ")
        email_template = forms.CharField(label=u"Modèle du message",
                    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 90, 'rows': 30}),
                    help_text="Utiliser les macros %ELECTION_URL% et %ELECTION_PASSWD%. Optionnellement: %VOTER_FIRSTNAME%.",
                    validators=[validate_template])
        attachment1 = forms.FileField(label=u"Attachement 1", required=False)
        attachment2 = forms.FileField(label=u"Attachement 2", required=False)

    def template_instance(tmpl, voter) :
        ELECTION_URL = "http://%s%s" % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, el.get_absolute_url())
        return tmpl.replace("%ELECTION_URL%", ELECTION_URL).replace(
                    "%ELECTION_PASSWD%", voter.passwd).replace(
                    "%VOTER_FIRSTNAME%", voter.member.firstname)

    message = None
    mode = "init"
    voters = None
    if request.method == "POST" :
        form = MailingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() :
            d = form.cleaned_data
            message = {
                "from": d["email_from"],
                "subject": d["email_subject"],
                "attachment1" : d["attachment1"],
                "attachment2" : d["attachment2"],
            }
            if d["email_to"] == "hasnotvoted":
                voters = el.voter.filter(hasvoted=False)
            else :
                voters = el.voter.all()

            if "do_it" in request.POST :
                def prep_attach( uf ) :
                    if uf :
                        return { "name": uf.name, "data": uf.read(), "content_type": uf.content_type }
                message["attachment1"] = prep_attach(message["attachment1"])
                message["attachment2"] = prep_attach(message["attachment2"])
                for voter in voters :
                    msg_txt = template_instance(d["email_template"], voter)
                    email = EmailMessage(message["subject"], msg_txt, message["from"],
                                [voter.member.email])
                    def attach( uf ) :
                        if uf :
                            email.attach(uf["name"], uf["data"], uf["content_type"])
                    attach(message["attachment1"])
                    attach(message["attachment2"])
                    email.send()
                context = { "election": el,
                            "voters": voters,
                          }
                return render(request, "election/mailing-ok.html", context)

            else :
                mode = "preview"
                class member :
                    firstname = u"Loïc"
                m = member()
                class voter :
                    passwd = "PASSWD_TEST"
                    member = m
                message["preview"] = template_instance(d["email_template"], voter())

    else :
        form = MailingForm()

    context = { "election": el,
                "voters": voters,
                "form": form,
                "mode": mode,
                "message": message,
              }
    return render(request, "election/mailing-form.html", context)
```

I checked the mentionned lines, if I remember well, but apparently they had not changed from Django 1.3.

Anyone of you know what the problem is? I know that this will be a long task to do the upgrade, but we really need to upgrade our applications!
I am also open to all the good suggestions you could share with me to do this upgrade!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include the relevant part of the code that relates to your issue.

Comment: 1.3 to 1.9 is a huge upgrade. Ideally, you'd step through each version in between and fix issues one by one. If that's not practical, try upgrading to 1.8 instead. It's a long term support release, so you'll have some time before you have to upgrade to 1.9 (or straight to the next LTS, 1.11).

Comment: In addition to Alasdair's suggestion, I'd stress that you need to review the backwards-incompatible changes at each step and apply any necessary changes to your code before moving forward again. Having such an old site, you might also consider starting with a fresh installation of whichever Django version you decide to target, adding your apps and wiring them up based on the current project structure, which I think has changed significantly since 1.3.

Comment: I do agree with @Alasdair it is huge upgrade. You should reconsider this upgrade. I also checked your project on github, I would suggest you to remove codes which create form to forms.py.

Comment: Alasdair: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I will do the upgrade version by version, it should be probably easier in this way. I did'nt have this idea at the beginning...

kugphu: I try to make it in emergency, so I am not sure that your solution will be so easy for me to do it during my freetime.

FatmaT: Yeah, you are right, I will check it with an other of my project. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Change the imports to:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views
```

Change your `urlpatterns` to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<election_id>\d+)/$', views.vote),
    url(r'^(?P<election_id>\d+)/ok/$', TemplateView.as_view(template = "election/vote-ok.html")),
    url(r'^(?P<election_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results),
    url(r'^(?P<election_id>\d+)/mailing/$', views.mailing),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected this file. Still don't work, I will try the solution proposed by Alasdair.